# If decorators stack in buttom-up approach then why don't they execute in that manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to get to know flow of functions calls in decorators but can't understand `ordinary()` and `trace()` functions output.

As decorators works in bottom-up approach they should execute in this manner: `trace(ordinary())` → `make_list()` → `trace(inner())`.

**According to my understanding the output should be this:**

```
TRACE: calling ordinary() with (), {}
TRACE: ordinary() returned I am Ordinary
making list of: I am Ordinary
TRACE: calling inner() with (), {}
TRACE: inner() returned ['I', 'am', 'Ordinary']
```

**But the output is this:**

```
TRACE: calling inner() with (), {}
TRACE: calling ordinary() with (), {}
TRACE: ordinary() returned I am Ordinary
making list of: I am Ordinary
TRACE: inner() returned ['I', 'am', 'Ordinary']
```

**Code:**

```
import functools

##################### DECORATORS #####################

def uppercase(func):
    def wrapper():
        original_result = func()
        modified_result = original_result.upper()
        return modified_result
    return wrapper

def make_list(func):
    def inner():
        y = func()
        print("making list of: "+y)
        z = y.split()
        return z
    return inner

def trace(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print(f'TRACE: calling {func.__name__}()'
              f' with {args}, {kwargs}')

        original_result = func(*args,**kwargs)

        print(f'TRACE: {func.__name__}() '
              f'returned {original_result}')
        return original_result
    return wrapper

#################### FUNCTIONS #########################

@trace
@uppercase
def greet():
    return 'hello'

@trace
@make_list
@trace
def ordinary():
    return "I am Ordinary"

################# FUNCTION CALLS ##################

greet()
print('\n')
ordinary()
```

Comment: Decorators apply to what follows them, so `greet` becomes `greet = trace(uppercase(greet))` and `ordinary` becomes `ordinary = trace(make_list(trace(ordinary)))`. How the resulting function behaves is entirely up to what those functions do with their arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Ry- when it is laid flat it is making some sense